# C++ Displaying a Text File...("Echo" a Text File)

Tags: c++, file-io, fileinputstream, readfile

So I'm really stuck trying to figured this bug on the program that is preventing me from displaying the text of my program..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
ifstream infile;
ofstream offile;

char text[1024];
cout <<"Please enter the name of the file: \n";
cin >> text;

infile.open(text);

string scores; // this lines...

getline(infile, scores, '\0'); // is what I'm using...

cout << scores << endl; // to display the file...
```

---

```
string name1;
int name2;
string name3;
int name4;
infile >> name1;
infile >> name2;
infile >> name3;
infile >> name4;

cout << "these two individual with their age add are" << name2 + name4 <<endl;

// 23 + 27

//the result I get is a bunch of numbers...

return 0;

}
```

Is there any way cleaner or simple method i can used to display the file ?

All the method in the internet are difficult to understand or keep track due to
the file is open in loop..

I want a program that you type the name of the file and displays the file
the file will contain the following...

```
jack 23 
smith 27
```

Also I need to obtain data from the file now I'm using the above code to obtain that information from the file...

Comment: I'm pretty sure `std::cout << infile.rdbuf();` will do it.

Comment: std::cout << infile.rdbuf();

Answer (score 1):

loop is probably the best thing you can do.
so if you know the format you could simply do it like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int printParsedFile(string fileName) {  // declaration of a function that reads from file passed as argument
    fstream f;     // file stream
    f.open(fileName.c_str(), ios_base::in);     // open file for reading
    if (f.good()) {     // check if the file can be read
        string tmp;     // temp variable we will use for getting chunked data
        while(!f.eof()) {     // read data until the end of file is reached
            f >> tmp;     // get first chunk of data
            cout << tmp << "\t";     // and print it to the console
            f >> tmp;     // get another chunk
            cout << tmp << endl;     // and print it as well

    } else {
        return -1; // failed to open the file
    }
    return 0; // file opened and read successfully
}
```

you can call then this function for example in your main() function to read and display file passed as argument

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
     string file;
     cout << "enter name of the file to read from: "
     cin >> file;
     printParsedFile(file);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: but which section will display the file ?? I want to know which section will display the file...

Comment: I updated it with comments so that you can understand it better. Basically, supposing you know format of data in the file you're reading (eg. 2 values per line) you can easily parse it by splitting the data into chunks like these. data from the stream will be read until a space between values is reached, so the only thing you have to actually do is to ensure the format of the data is consistent

Answer (score 0):

I personally use stringstreams for reading one line at a time and parsing it:

For example:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <stringstream>
#include <string>

std::string filename;

// Get name of your file
std::cout << "Enter the name of your file ";
std::cin >> filename;

// Open it
std::ifstream infs( filename );
std::string line;

getline( infs, line );

while( infs.good() ) {
    std::istringstream lineStream( line );
    std::string name;
    int age;
    lineStream >> name >> age;
    std::cout << "Name = " << name << " age = " << age << std::endl;

    getline( infs, line );
}
```

Comment: but I want to display the file.. then display the what you provided above...thanks for the simplify...